# Show post with thumbnails only

Tags: custom-post-types

I only want to show my post with thumbnails. Given below is the code I used to show all the post, but now I need to ammend it in such a way that only post with thumbnails should appear. Also these post are showing on oother page as well where I just need to show them normally, its the homepage where I need to show post with thumbnails. I need quick help. Thanks

```
$events = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($events->have_posts()):
        $result  .= "<div class='featuredin container'>";
        $result  .= "<ul class='featured-in-content'>";
        while($events->have_posts()): $events->the_post();
            $start2 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'links-ev-sdate', true);  

            $result .= '<li class="event_url"><a target="_blank" href="'.$start2.'">'. get_the_post_thumbnail();
            $result  .= '</a></li>';
        endwhile;
            $result  .= '</ul>';
        $result .= "</div>";
    else:
        $result .= '<span>Events Not Found</span>';
    endif;  
    return $result;
```

Comment: Can you please include the part of your code where `$args` is defined in your code?

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your arguments before passing to `WP_Query`. Also, you may use 
`meta_query` to acheive what you are looking for.

Here is some documentation to help you with your futur developments.

**WP_Query**

[Link to the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters)
Show posts associated with a certain custom field.

This part of the query is parsed by `WP_Meta_Query`, so check the docs for it as well in case this list of arguments isn’t up to date.

**WP_Meta_Query**

[Link to the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/)
Used for generating SQL clauses that filter a primary query according to metadata keys and values. Filter their results by object metadata, by generating JOIN and WHERE subclauses to be attached to the primary SQL query string.

So the goal is to find the metadata key you want to find. To do so, you can go in your database and look for your `meta_key` in the table named `wp_postmeta`.

In this case, we would search for `_thumbnail_id` in our table.

`SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '_thumbnail_id';`

Once you found the `meta_key` you want to work with, just build your array.

**Here is the final code**

```
<?php 
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(

    // Your default arguments
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
    // ...

    // This is the part where you need to work with WP_Meta_Query
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => '_thumbnail_id'
    )
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();

        // Display your post information
    }

} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```